# CSS - Background Opacity Not Working

Tags: html, css

I want a parent div to fill the screen with a transparent background but I can't seem to get this to work with the following code.

The parent div only appears as a solid colour.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <h5>Search</h5>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your are using 50% opaque **white** on 100% opaque white. How exactly do you expect that to become visible?

Comment: What would an opaque white look like? Very curious to understand.

Comment: Your `.outer` has only child elements with position: absolute;. Its `height: 100%;` refers to the parent element's height (here: `body`), which is 0.

Comment: @connexo - A full height background would have a opacity of 0.5.
Then within that (the inner) would be a solid white - this inner div would have a smaller height. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your are using 50% opaque white on 100% opaque white. How exactly do you expect that to become visible?

Also, your `body` has a computed height of `0`. That makes `.outer` have 100% of 0 - guess what that is...

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background-color: #f0f0f0; }
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h5>Search</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the vh (viewport height) instead of the 100% height. When you use the 100% height, it takes the 100% of parent and the parent is body which height is 0px.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100vh;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <h5>Search</h5>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a div with a white background won't work when overlapping another white element.

However, even if you were to change the colour of `.outer` to grey (as I've done in my example), it still won't fill the full height of the screen.

Instead of using `height: 100%`, you can view `height: 100vh` to fill the screen. You can learn more about `vh` (Viewport-percentage) from this [article](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

Here's a work example:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 100vh;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <h5>Search</h5>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `vw` is viewport **width**, not viewport **height**.

Answer (score 0):

parent div's opacity wont achieved when there is a solid background on the child and the `.outer` as no height so its not possible to show it. (because of `position:absolute`)

May be reverse these backgrounds and give position relative will make u understandable about how it works like below.

Note:Even `position:absolute;` in both places makes some sense

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

    <h5>Search</h5>

  </div>

</div>
```